# NASM keyboard emulation

Tags: assembly, ubuntu, input, keyboard, nasm

I have been doing basic NASM coding, and I wondered if it is possible to emulate a keypress using NASM. If so, how?

I'm using Ubuntu linux 10.04 and a Pentium R T4300 processer if it matters.

Comment: What operating system? Or are you running on bare-hardware? (ie, your own OS)

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Linux system calls (int 0x80)](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html)

Comment: that page doesn't have keyboard in it once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible paths to proceed depending on what you want to do exactly. None of them are very simple (like for example in DOS) since there is no single globally accessable keyboard buffer in Linux. I don't think it's possible to inject events into the kernel driver for your keyboard (correct me if i'm wrong). Unless, of course, you modify the driver. You can create a virtual keyboard and configure your programs to read events from that in addition to your real one. Or if you only need it to work in a specific environment on top of Linux (for example X) you might find some usable function in it's API.

For some scenarios on the other hand it can be very simple. If you want to automatically answer some questions in an interactive terminal application you do it like: `yes | someapplication` or `echo yyny | someapplication`. Obviously what was shell code and not nasm code. Translating it is left as an exercise for the reader.